# Trying to create a matrix to visualize the workload of a group of people

Tags: matrix, powerbi, gantt-chart

Iam trying to create a matrix or table or a gantt chart to create a follow up of the workload of people. I have this data in excel: Name of project, hours a week (how much time they work in the project), start date, end date and name. (all columns).

So it would be name of the person in rows, the weeks of the year in the columns and in the cells the workload.
My biggest problem is that the workload is showing only in the start date in the matrix, and i want it to show for every week. And also, someone can be in 2 or more projects, so the sum should be updated to the projects, and when they finish.

Someone know how to do this? Im having problems and I´m not very good at power bi, so it may not be as difficult as i think, but i just don´t know hot to do it.

PLEASE :)

I try to create for every projects, the row of the week that each one of them are in, because the dates are only in the beginning and end date of the project but i couldn´t.